# lookahead and lookbehind regex not matching

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have been trying to get some regex statements to work for the past few hours, but I can not seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

here is what I currently have:

```
(?<!.)\d{4}[\.]\d{2}(?!.)|(?<!.)\d{4}(?!.)
```

The data I am trying to match looks like

```
1234.00
1546.34
1234
2345
```

but it is mixed into other text and numbers. I need to filter out anything with preceding or proceeding characters so it does not match something like the following

d12394-005

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'\b(?<!\.)\d{4}(?:\.\d{2})?\b(?!\.)', text)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Au82kN/1))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is it, you could consider making a post out of it.

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mre], including some example input and your Python code. BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: @Thefourthbird On second thought, OP simply wants word boundaries. `re.findall(r'\b\d{4}(?:\.\d{2})?\b', text)`.

Comment: Word boundaries, makes sense. Thanks everyone!